# How to use the Featured Item slider 2.0 in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms

I am very new to orchard CMS... i am trying to make a site in orchard CMS as this is my first site in orchard... i am facing a fair bit of problem and hindrances to over come... my background of the CMS for creating websites is wordpress/PHP....

but now there in this project i have a problem for the slider in the home page! how could i implement a slider in the home page... after searching a bit i have found to use the featured image slider.. i have tried to implement it... i have installed the module and made the featured group... now MY PROBLEM IS WHERE I CAN ADD THE IMAGES IN THE SLIDER... AS THE FEATURE ITEM FROM THE MENU ONLY SHOW THREE FIELDS HEADLINE,SUB-HEADLINE, AND LINKURL...

kindly let me know where do i can add the images in this slider and show them on the home page of my site....

Thanks alot in advance....

Answer (score 1):

After hell of the search i have got the solution for that purpose... i am elaborating my answer step wise so that the new guys like me should understand that without an inconvenience...

normally orchard CMS uses nivo slider bydefault... if you want to use other sliders follow the same path as pasted below...

1: if you have download the Orchard CMS there will be a Jquery function in the layout.cshtml and the jquery file will also be linked in the script tag, pointing to the package of Jquery in Js or anyother folder...

2: Get the name of the div for which the Jquery is pointing to... normally the name will be "slider".... Copy that name and paste it in your home from CMS... but make sure to keep the name of the div same as the Jquery function narrates which is ("slider").

3:Link your images in the Div...

and browse the site in the browser and enjoy the slider...

Answer (score 0):

I have a fantastic [tutorial](http://www.pepfry.com/tutorials/image-slider-in-orchard-cms-featured-item-slider) on [pepfry.com](http://www.pepfry.com/tutorials/image-slider-in-orchard-cms-featured-item-slider) for this issue. I have a complete tutorial where I show you all the steps to successfully install the '[Featured Item Slider](http://www.pepfry.com/tutorials/image-slider-in-orchard-cms-featured-item-slider)' with screenshots.

I also have a video on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqMqsc-XE4w) where you can see the [Image slider working successfully](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqMqsc-XE4w).

Regards!
Sumesh M.S

Comment: yeh i read your tutorial was very good, however there are reported problems with 1.8+, now you have stated that you have it working fine in 1.8, however both types of installation methods i have tried + editing the driver to point to the medialibrary instead have had 0 luck so far.  could you reflect on this?

Comment: Hi Steven,

Sorry, I couldn't attend this comment sooner. Let me have a check at my steps used.
I'll get back to you on this.